# C# WPF Setting 2 different GridViewColumn to maximum width

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have 2 different GridViewColumns in 2 different child controls. Below is just an example of what one of the GridViewColumns looks like.

```
<GridViewColumn Width="auto" x:Name="StatusColumn" HeaderTemplate="{StaticResource HeaderTemplate}">
   <GridViewColumnHeader Content="Status" Tag="DisplayStatus" HorizontalContentAlignment="Left" Click="GridViewColumnHeader_Click"/>
      <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
           <TextBlock Text="{Binding FileStatus.DisplayStatus, Mode=OneWay}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Style="{StaticResource ConflictStateStyle}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
   </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
</GridViewColumn>
```

As you can see the Width is set to "auto".
After the control is created this GridViewColumn gets set to the maximum size text in the column.

Now what I want is that I have 2 different GridViewColumns, and I want to set the width of each of them, to the maximum size of each.
IE in the code below I have width = **Math.Max(remoteColumn.ActualWidth, localColumn.ActualWidth)**

Below is an example of what I have done, that does not work:

```
int measureInitializeCount = 0;
protected override Size MeasureOverride(Size availableSize)
{
  if ((LocalList.Count > 0 || RemoteList.Count > 0) && measureInitializeCount++ == 1)
  {
    var measure = base.MeasureOverride(availableSize);

    var remoteGridView = (GridView)RemoteSyncCollectionControl.DataTreeGrid.View;
    var localGridView = (GridView)RemoteSyncCollectionControl.DataTreeGrid.View;

    InitializeColumnWidth(remoteGridView.Columns[0], localGridView.Columns[0]);
    InitializeColumnWidth(remoteGridView.Columns[1], localGridView.Columns[1]);
    InitializeColumnWidth(remoteGridView.Columns[2], localGridView.Columns[2]);
    InitializeColumnWidth(remoteGridView.Columns[3], localGridView.Columns[3]);

    void InitializeColumnWidth(GridViewColumn remoteColumn, GridViewColumn localColumn)
    {
      var width = Math.Max(remoteColumn.ActualWidth, localColumn.ActualWidth);

      if (width > 0 && width != float.NaN)
      {
        (remoteColumn).Width = width;
        (localColumn).Width = width;
      }
    }
  }

  return base.MeasureOverride(availableSize);
}
```

---

In the picture below you can see that the columns of the top and the bottom do not line up as I want them to

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the `if ((LocalList.Count > 0 || RemoteList.Count > 0) && measureInitializeCount++ == 0)` condition. When wpf draws the window for the first time it'll call `MeasureOverride` method. However at that time `DataTreeGrid`s are not yet visible so they 'll not have calculated column widths for the GridViews inside them.

What you want to do is wait for the control to draw itself first and then set appropriate column width. Update you code to `if ((LocalList.Count > 0 || RemoteList.Count > 0) && measureInitializeCount++ == 1)` and it should work like a charm!

Comment: I have done what you recommended - Above I posted a picture of what the final result looks like and you can see that it did not work at all. All the columns of the top and bottom should line up

Comment: @IlanKeshet Not sure if you posted all of your code. Check working version @ https://github.com/dipen08it419/Stackoverflow-wpf

Comment: Hey -- I'm looking into what you showed. I have been busy with other stuff.